# What’s the XPath expression to select an attribute based on its prefix?

Tags: xpath

I need to select a node with a id attribute that I only know part of the value.

If I have several `<tr>` elements:

```
<tr id="foobar[1234]"></td><tr id="foobar[1235]"></td><tr id="foobar[1236]"></td><tr id="bar[1]"></td><tr id="foobar[1237]"></td><tr id="bar[12]"></td>
```

I only want to select the id's that start with `foobar`.

I've tried:

```
//tr[@id='foobar*']
```

but it doesn’t work.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
//tr[starts-with(@id,'foobar')]
```

A list of XPath 1.0 functions: http://www.edankert.com/xpathfunctions.html

If your implementations supports XPath 2.0, you get a lot of other ones.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
//tr[@id*="foobar"]
```

I'm not certain this works, but it may.