# What’s the XPath equivalent to the CSS selector [attr^=]?

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

In CSS selectors, you can select an element with an attribute who’s value starts with a string.

E.g. both of these paragraphs

```
<p class="geoff"></p>
<p class="geoff-de-geoff"></p>
```

can be selected using this selector:

```
p[class^=geoff]
```

Is there an equivalent in XPath? I know how to select based on the complete value of an attribute, i.e.

```
//p[@class='geoff']
```

Can you select based on the start of the attribute’s value in XPath?

Comment: Ah — see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357430/xpath-to-select-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is [starts-with](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) function:

```
//p[starts-with(@class,'geoff')]
```

**ADD-ON:**

If you are interested in mapping css selectors to xpath queries, you can have a look at [this](http://plasmasturm.org/log/444/) table, unfortunately there is no answer to your question (but you already got it), but there are other selectors. Also interesting page [CSS => XPath](http://css2xpath.appspot.com/), your task it solved as:

```
descendant-or-self::p[starts-with(@class, 'geoff')]
```

well, quite good answer generated ;)

Comment: Hey, nice links there. Boom. Accepted answer status is yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
//p[starts-with(@class, 'geoff')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha — the `starts-with()` function does it.

```
//p[starts-with(@class,'geoff')]
```