# How do I retrieve objects based on a partial custom attribute name in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following element:

```
<div data-offer="MTs3O29sZG5hdnkuY29tOzQxMDYy" class="Offer__Card-sc-14rx0hy-0 iBdrTi"></div>
```

I need to find it with scrapy but I have two comlpications. The class can change so it is not going to have that value. Pretty much off the table.

The second problem is that **data-offer** value can vary between data-offer, data-offer-promo, data-offer-double

Do you know how can I find this elements based on a partial attribute name?
Like bring me everything that has a custom attribute "data-offer*"
Or everything that starts with it works too, but not the value, the attribute name.

I tried this with no success

```
 response.css('[div::attr^="data-offer"]')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3357430/939364

Answer (score 0):

You can find those elements using beautifulSoup. This will find the first div element that has a "data-offer" attribute:

> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')
> results = soup.find("div", {"data-offer" : True})
> ```

You could also get a list with all the elements that have the same condition:

> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')
> results = soup.find_all("div", {"data-offer" : True})
> ```

Comment: Thanks!, I have the whole tool built on Scrapy (alternative to beautifulSoup). I'm trying to find a way with this one, although this is important enough to switch frameworks.

Comment: There is no need to choose one, you can use both. 'response.body' is the response from your Scrapy request.